# Database update query

Tags: sql, database, ms-access-2013

Consider the following table:

```
Employee(empid, emp_name,emp_dob,emp_doj,emp_basicsalary,emp_medallowance).
```

Create an update query that increments employee’s salary on the following conditions.

```
If basic salary is < Rs.50,000
    increment=20%
else
    increment=15%
```

If two update queries are executed one for each

Comment: use case when in update

Comment: @AmeyaDeshpande i dont have any idea about case :( . This question is just given to me to search on internet and do it. i will be grateful if u help me in this

Answer (score 2):

This works for you:

```
update Employee
set salary = case 
 when salary < 50000 then salary * 1.20
 else salary * 1.15
end;
```

Comment: thanks for ur reply.but it has some problem saying
syntax error (missing operator )in query expression slasry <50000 then salry *1.2 else salary*1.5

Comment: Your query could have type error - you had typed different column for 'salary'. just copy and paste this line, update Employee set salary = case 
 when salary < 50000 then salary * 1.20
 else salary * 1.15
end

Answer (score 1):

You can use only 1 update query with `CASE WHEN` as below:

```
UPDATE Employee 
SET emp_basicsalary = CASE WHEN emp_basicsalary < 50,000 
                           THEN emp_basicsalary * 1.2 
                           ELSE emp_basicsalary * 1.15 
                       END
```

Comment: Remove the comma from your 50,000 ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
update Employee
set salary = case when salary < 50000 then salary * 1.2 
             else salary * 1.15
             end
```

In MS Access you can try this:

```
update Employee
set salary = IIF(salary < 50000, salary*1.5, salary * 1.15)
```

or you can try using `Switch`

```
UPDATE Employee
SET salary= Switch(
    salary < 50000, salary * 1.2,
    salary >= 50000, salary * 1.15,
    );
```

Note that MS Access does not have `Case when then`

Answer (score 0):

first run this one

UPDATE `Employee` SET emp_basicsalary = 1.15*emp_basicsalary where emp_basicsalary >= 50000;

And then

UPDATE `Employee` SET emp_basicsalary = 1.2*emp_basicsalary where emp_basicsalary < 50000;

Comment: No need to have two update statement. Look at the other answers :)

Comment: it requires a single update query as RahulTripathi said
and @RahulTripathi thanx for the help but in query it has some problems.says syntax error im using ms access 2013

Comment: @MuhammadUsman:- Updated my answer with the MS Access version. Check  that!

Comment: @RahulTripathi thanks for ur support.
can u please think of another possible way to implement this type of query??

Comment: @MuhammadUsman:- You are welcome. And if the answer helped you then do accept it. (Right tick mark turns green when clicked)

Comment: @MuhammadUsman:- Why you want to have alternate method. This is the best way to proceed with your problem.

Comment: @RahulTripathi its the best way no doubt but i have to find two ways to fulfill requirements.

Comment: @MuhammadUsman:- I have already added two ways of doing the query. using the IIF and using the SWITCH.

Comment: @RahulTripathi can u please give me the switch query to work  in ms access?

Comment: yes it may be possible with 1 query , but my way is also correct and simple, in any case any records will not be updated twice, because first we increased salary of those whose salary is already greater than 50000 and then for for those whose salary is less than 50000

Comment: @MuhammadUsman:- I have added that in my answer. Please check

Comment: @RahulTripathi thanks bro thank u very much u solved a big issue thanks for ur support.

Comment: @AniketSingh:- That is not a query which you can suggest for this situation. Making multiple hits on a database is not a good approach(*and infact considered bad*) when you have a better query option. And to inform you that even with *switch* it will not be updated twice.

Comment: @Rahul. Ok, got it. Thnx.